# Any way to know how many trimmed blocks are on a SSD?

Tags: ssd

I have replaced my laptop's HDD with a 480 GB SSD.

I left a 20 GB gap at the end of the disk for over-provisioning (the location doesn't matter because it is a SSD). And the main partition has lots of free space.
I used the trim feature integrated to Windows for the main partition. 
I then **hope** this SSD is correctly trimmed, but I have no proof.

Does someone know a way to find how many trimmed blocks/sectors/percentage/whatever are on a SSD?

As there is not standard for this, I'm afraid this require to communicate with the firmware, which involve different method for different SSD.
This is not a problem if this require to boot from Linux.

This is a SanDisk SDSSDA-480G 
I already used SanDisk SSD Dashboard, but the values reported are only what Windows reports (this is written in the program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you search for are only inside a private part on the SSD. Currently no standard way to access the internal SSD controler and its data structures. So even if possible it will be device specific.
I suspect the existence of such programs in the hands of manufacturers, but never saw one. That said, I never searched for them.

With a crucial MX300 SSD I found trimmed blocks are read faster than non trimmed ones. I did it on a big trimmed area where I overprovisionned and in an empty partition.
I also tested it against a partition filled with zeros, to check if highly compressed data could lead to the same result: compressed data were a little slower and distinguishable from trimmed areas.
I don't think this will be easy for small areas, thus difficult to know the real count, but easy enought to be sure big areas are ok.
Probably each SSD respond differently. I tested only ONE of them.

In you case this may be ok to verify is the overprovisionned area is trimmed, and if your low-data partition seems trimmed.
For the regular trimming operated by Windows, I think you can be confident.

Answer (score 1):

Users of some SSDs are reporting that `smartctl -A` is giving them a `Wear_Leveling_Count`.

Others, like me, don't seem to have a way to find out. My drive model is reported as `TOSHIBA THNSNK128GVN8`. I have some `Unknown_SSD_Attribute` but they don't seem to have values that seem to be representing my discarded blocks. `smartctl` also says `Not in smartctl database`, I don't know if that may be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes little sense, the [TRIM command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)) is at it's most basic your OS informing the microcode in the SSD that a certain block no longer contains data and that it can be wiped/used for wear levelling or whatever.

For monitoring health and wear data either use a tool from the vendor (for instance the [SanDisk SSD Dashboard](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15108/~/sandisk-ssd-dashboard-support-information) or monitor the industry standard [SMART data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)  reported by the drive.

Comment: The Linux `fstrim` command will explicitly report what he wants, e.g. `/: 36.3 GiB (38967480320 bytes) trimmed`

Comment: @MichaelHampton  No, `fstrim` reports what it told the block device to do, but it doesn't report on the current actual status of the block device. There is no way to use `fstrim` to find out how many hardware blocks are considered in use, and according to https://superuser.com/a/1164940/37154 there is apparently no other trivial way to know either.

Comment: @clacke Indeed. But if you can't trust the block device to (eventually) actually unmap the blocks, then you probably need a new block device.

Comment: @michaelhampton The drive is probably fine. What I cannot trust is whether I understand all the layers enough and configured them correctly to be sure that one of them didn't swallow the request, when I'm running fstrim on a filesystem on an LV on a dm_crypt.

Comment: @clacke Now that would make an interesting Q&A.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think *Any way to know how many trimmed blocks are on a SDD?* pretty much covers that. ;-)